# Hyperpriors for hierarchical models with Stan

Tags: bayesian, pymc, stan

I'm looking to fit a model to estimate multiple probabilities for binomial data with Stan. I was using beta priors for each probability, but I've been reading about using hyperpriors to pool information and encourage shrinkage on the estimates.

I've seen this example to define the hyperprior in pymc, but I'm not sure how to do something similar with Stan

```
@pymc.stochastic(dtype=np.float64)
def beta_priors(value=[1.0, 1.0]):
    a, b = value
    if a <= 0 or b <= 0:
        return -np.inf
    else:
        return np.log(np.power((a + b), -2.5))

a = beta_priors[0]
b = beta_priors[1]
```

With a and b then being used as parameters for the beta prior.

Can anybody give me any pointers on how something similar would be done with Stan?

Comment: The manual contains many examples of how to build hierarchical and multilvel models (what you're talking about here).  Our basic recommendations for priors are in the manual chapter in regression and also on this wiki page:  https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations

Comment: There are also case studies on hierarchical models, specifically one directly about binary variables that contrasts hyperpriors for binomials with a logistic regression with only an intercept (the upshot is that you probably don't want to be using beta-binomials or Dirichlet-multinomials):  http://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/pool-binary-trials.html

Comment: @BobCarpenter That looks really helpful - thanks. I'm doing this for AB testing, and for more complicated tests I did think working in a regression framework would make more sense. Being able to rank variants as in the case study could also be useful for communicating results to colleagues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following suggestions in the comments I'm not sure that I will follow this approach, but for reference I thought I'd at least post the answer to my question of how this could be accomplished in Stan.

After some asking around on Stan Discourses and further investigation I found that the solution was to set a custom density distribution and use the `target +=` syntax. So the equivalent for Stan of the example for pymc would be:

```
parameters {
  real<lower=0> a;
  real<lower=0> b;
  real<lower=0,upper=1> p;
  ...
}

model {
  target += log((a + b)^-2.5);

  p ~ beta(a,b)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To properly normalize that, you need a Pareto distribution.  For example, if you want a distribution `p(a, b) ∝ (a + b)^(-2.5)`, you can use

```
a + b ~ pareto(L, 1.5);
```

where `a + b > L`.  There's no way to normalize the density with support for all values greater than or equal to zero---it needs a finite `L` as a lower bound.  There's a discussion of using just this prior as the count component of a hierarchical prior for a simplex.

If `a` and `b` are parameters, they can either both be constrained to be positive, or you can leave `a` unconstrained and declare

```
real<lower = L - a> b;
```

to insure `a + b > L`.  `L` can be a small constant or something more reasonable given your knowledge of `a` and `b`.

You should be careful because this will not identify `a + b`.  We use this construction as a hierarchical prior for simplexes as:

```
parameters {
  real<lower = 1> kappa;
  real<lower = 0, upper = 1> phi;
  vector<lower = 0, upper = 1>[K] theta;

model {
  kappa ~ pareto(1, 1.5);  // power law prior
  phi ~ beta(a, b);  // choose your prior for theta
  theta ~ beta(kappa * phi, kappa * (1 - phi));  // vectorized
```

There's an extended example in my Stan case study of repeated binary trials, which is reachable from the case studies page on the [Stan web site](http://mc-stan.org) (the case study directory is currently linked under the documentation link from the users tab).